# How do I make this add-in toolbar button work in ArcMap 10.2 using the ESRI provided Python Add-In Wizard (i'm following a tutorial)

Tags: python, gis

I'm following a tutorial here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/button/014p0000001z000000/

I have added the code to the .py file and installed the add-in using the makeaddin.py file and Test001.esriaddin file yet when I press the button in ArcMap, nothing happens. It's supposed to zoom to the selected features. I have ArcMap 10.2 and indicated so in the Python Add-In Wizard provided by ESRI. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer in this matter. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

    class ZoomToSelectedFeatures(object):
        """Implementation for Test001_addin.btn1 (Button)"""
        def __init__(self):
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = False
           # Implementation of OnClick method of Button's class
           def onClick(self):
                # Get the current map document and the first data frame.
                mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
                df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
                # Call the zoomToSelectedFeatures() method of the data frame class
                df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Wow! it won't let me post images unless I have 10 reputation...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct your indent for onClick method.

```
class ZoomToSelectedFeatures(object):
    """Implementation for Test001_addin.btn1 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
        # Implementation of OnClick method of Button's class
    def onClick(self):
        # Get the current map document and the first data frame.
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        # Call the zoomToSelectedFeatures() method of the data frame class
        df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```